# Compare Meteor.subcribe() Vs this.subscribe() [Meteor + Blaze]

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have two pages/Template,

1. Dashboard (contains some User specific data as well).
2. Users.

I am using Meteor 1.5 with Blaze Template. Landing Page is Dashboard. I am using the common subscription for Collection `Users` in both Templates.

**Scenario 1**

When I use `Meteor.subscribe('Users')` in **Dashboard's** `template.onCreated()` and go to **Users** page, I see some already subscribed data coming back from **Dashboard's** subscription.

*CODE:*

```
Template.DashBoard.onCreated(function(){
    Meteor.subscribe('Users');
});

Template.Users.onCreated(function(){
    Meteor.subscribe('Users');
});
```

**Scenario 2**

When I use `this.subscribe('Users')` in **Dashboard's** `template.onCreated()` and go to **Users** page, I get a Fresh Subscription happening here and no data carry over from **Dashboard's** subscription.

*CODE:*

```
Template.DashBoard.onCreated(function(){
    this.subscribe('Users');
});

Template.Users.onCreated(function(){
    this.subscribe('Users');
});
```

**Question**

What is the difference between `Meteor.subscribe('Users')` and `this.subscribe('Users')` ? What can be the impact of using `this.subscribe('Users')` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in Meteor documentation, `this.subscribe` within Template code will be automatically unsubscribed when the template instance is destroyed.

Whereas `Meteor.subscribe` needs to be explicitly unsubscribed if you want it to.

The decision to use one or the other depends on your app structure. If you are sure the data is relevant only for a given template, then use template scoped subscription, i.e. `this.subscribe`.

If the data is used across several pages, either use the "global" form, or scoped at a higher template level (one that persists through your pages, e.g. on layout).