# Meteor.users publish and subscribe do not match

Tags: meteor

I have removed the `auto-publish` package from my Meteor app and I have also created a publication on my server:

```
Meteor.publish("userData", function () {
    return Meteor.users.find(
            {_id: this.userId},
            {fields: {'profile': 0}}
        );
});
```

As you can see above I have set the `profile` to `0` which means I would like to exclude it.  However...

On my client I have this code:

```
Meteor.subscribe("userData", (param) => {
      console.log( Meteor.users.find(Meteor.userId()).fetch() )
    })
```

and the output still includes the profile:

```
createdAt: Sat May 19 2018 11:16:25 GMT+0800 (+08) {}
emails: [{…}]
profile: {name: "Second Second"}
services: {password: {…}, resume: {…}}
username: "seconduser"
_id: "ESmRokNscFcBA9yN4"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

What's the reason for this?

Comment: Meteor automatically publishes some fields of the current user's document. One of those fields it the `profile`. Note that publishing the data that you did (password hashes etc.) should not be done in a production system. I assume that you did it for testing purposes only, but I mention it so that nobody does this by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that some other [subscription](https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Meteor-subscribe) has subscribed to the `profile` field of the user.

You can find out if this is the case by looking at the information sent over the websocket.

1. Open the debugger,
2. find a "networking" tab,
3. find the websocket connection,
4. find the content or "frames".

There you can see which `subs` have been made and which updates the server publishes to a `collection`. See what it looks like without your sub; maybe the user doc is published already.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure whether you want to use `Meteor.subscribe()` or you want to use `this.subscribe()`. There is a lot of difference between them.

1. `Meteor.subscribe()` will keep subscription undestroyed when you change between screens/routes/UI.
2. `this.subscribe()` will have the scope of subscription till the life of `Template` exists. When you switch to other routes/path/UI, the subscription will be destroyed. This is used in a specific case when you have multiple kinds of subscription among consecutive transitions of the screen and problem occurs for unwanted data shown in UI despite filtering in Collection Query.

For more insight, [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49708151/3296607).

Comming to your exact question, well when Meteor knows that you are a valid and logged in user, it sends entire Users specific collection fields `_id`, `emails`, `profile`, `username` on UI. So, it is recommended that you put only the required data into the User collection. Whether or not you make special kind of subscription to self-data, you will always be able to access your own data on UI, even on production build. You can check by putting `console.log(Meteor.user());` in chrome console. This is how `Meteor.user()` is made, whether you like it or not. It was assumed by MDG (Meteor Development Group) that when the user has logged in, a user can fully access his/her own data at UI as it is safe and valid.

see below image for reference,

[image]

Comment: Meteor does *not* automatically publish the entire user document to the current user but the `profile` key is always published.

Answer (score 0):

You see the `profile` field on the client since you have already edited and thus enabled this special field of the `User` object while creating or updating user. In order to secure this object from client-side modifications you can deny all writes from the client with the following server-side code.

```
// Deny all client-side updates to user documents
Meteor.users.deny({
    update () { return true; },
});
```

So, even though the `profile` field is be available on the client within the `Meteor.user()` object, no modification can be made by the client.

If it is a custom data that you publish than you can control its exposition in your way. For example, let's assume that we introduce a new field `customProfile` into the user object, than with the following code, the `customProfile` will not be visible to the client.

```
Meteor.publish("userData", function () {
    console.log('publishing userData with id', this.userId);
    return Meteor.users.find(
            {_id: this.userId},
            {fields: {'customProfile': 0}}
        );
});
```

You may find more information in the [guide](https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#publish-custom-data).